# Apply np.where or np.select to multiple column pairs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given a data `df` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'A1', 'A1'], [2, 'A2', 'B2', 1, 1], [3, 'B3', 'B3', 3, 2], [4, None, None]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'v1','v2','v3','v4'])
print(df)
```

Out:

```
   id    v1    v2   v3   v4
0   1    A1    A1  NaN  NaN
1   2    A2    B2  1.0  1.0
2   3    B3    B3  3.0  2.0
3   4  None  None  NaN  NaN
```

Let's say I need to check if multiple column pairs have identical content or same values:

```
col_pair = {'v1': 'v2', 'v3': 'v4'}
```

If I don't want to repeat `np.where` multiple times as follow, instead, I hope to apply `col_pair` or other possible solutions, how could I acheive that? Thanks.

```
df['v1_v2'] = np.where(df['v1'] == df['v2'], 1, 0)
df['v3_v4'] = np.where(df['v3'] == df['v4'], 1, 0)
```

The expected result:

```
   id    v1    v2   v3   v4 v1_v2 v3_v4
0   1    A1    A1  NaN  NaN     1   NaN
1   2    A2    B2  1.0  1.0     0     1
2   3    B3    B3  3.0  2.0     1     0
3   4  None  None  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need test also if both values in pair key-value are missing in [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and passed to [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
for k, v in col_pair.items():
    df[f'{k}_{v}'] = np.select([df[[k, v]].isna().all(axis=1),
                                df[k] == df[v]], [None,1], default=0)
```

Out:

```
   id    v1    v2   v3   v4 v1_v2 v3_v4
0   1    A1    A1  NaN  NaN     1  None
1   2    A2    B2  1.0  1.0     0     1
2   3    B3    B3  3.0  2.0     1     0
3   4  None  None  NaN  NaN  None  None
```

Comment: Please not if both two columns are `NaN`s or `None`s, I hope to it returns `NaN` for the output cell. ie. for `id = 0`, the value of `v3_v4` should be `NaN`.

Comment: Sorry, I found one problem in using dictionary `col_pair`, if I need to compare `v1_v2`, `v3_v4` and also `v1_v3`,  but cann't set `col_pair = {'v1': 'v2', 'v3': 'v4', 'v1': 'v3'}` since keys can't be duplicated in dict, any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: @ahbon - then use list of tuples like `col_pair = [('v1', 'v2'), ('v3', 'v4'), ('v1', 'v3')]` and in solution above change `for k, v in col_pair.items():` to `for k, v in col_pair:`